# dplyr::filter on sf object: Error in `vec_size()`: ! `x` must be a vector, not a <sfc_POLYGON/sfc> object

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

I loaded and filtered a geojson file (https://downtownrecovery.com/downtowns-original.geojson) using the code

```
library(dplyr); library(geojsonsf)
orig <- geojson_sf("downtowns-original.geojson")

orig %>%
  filter(city == "San Francisco")
```

It worked with R 4.2 and dplyr 1.1.1, but with R 4.3 and dplyr 1.1.3 (and vctrs 0.6.4) I get the error below.

```
Error in `vec_size()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <sfc_POLYGON/sfc> object.
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─new %>% filter(city == "San Francisco")
  2. ├─dplyr::filter(., city == "San Francisco")
  3. ├─dplyr:::filter.data.frame(., city == "San Francisco")
  4. │ ├─dplyr::dplyr_row_slice(.data, loc, preserve = .preserve)
  5. │ └─dplyr:::dplyr_row_slice.data.frame(.data, loc, preserve = .preserve)
  6. │   ├─dplyr::dplyr_reconstruct(vec_slice(data, i), data)
  7. │   │ └─dplyr:::dplyr_new_data_frame(data)
  8. │   │   ├─row.names %||% .row_names_info(x, type = 0L)
  9. │   │   └─base::.row_names_info(x, type = 0L)
 10. │   └─vctrs::vec_slice(data, i)
 11. └─vctrs:::stop_scalar_type(`<fn>`(`<s_POLYGO>`), "x", `<fn>`(vec_size()))
 12.   └─vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
```

What is the issue and is there anything I should do to resolve it?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the vctrs package; with R v4.3, dplyr v1.1.3 and vctrs v0.6.3 I had no error, with vctrs v0.6.4 I get the same error as you. Can you downgrade vctrs? Or are you looking for a 'proper' fix?

Comment: Seems to be a wrong `filter()` method,  `dplyr::filter()` instead of `sf:::filter.sf()` . Was it working before without loading `sf` ? Anyway,  you can use `sf::st_read()` /  `sf::read_sf()` with GeoJSON URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is - something to do with the changes in the vctrs package when updated to v0.6.4 - but if you load the sf package your code works. Perhaps it has something to do with the dplyr command aliases in sf (https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/tidyverse.html?q=filter.sf#ref-usage)?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
# install.packages("geojsonsf")
library(geojsonsf)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

orig <- geojson_sf("~/Desktop/downtowns-original.geojson")

orig %>%
  filter(city == "San Francisco")
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -122.4057 ymin: 37.78431 xmax: -122.3856 ymax: 37.80667
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>            city                       geometry
#> 1 San Francisco MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.4048 3...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>